# Hbase: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Action

Tags: hadoop, hbase

When I run my fat jar on the edge node of the cluster created from eclipse using build option, it runs fine.

But when I run the same code from eclipse IDE (all the properties of cluster are set properly), it gives below error:[image]

I am using only single maven dependency of HBase as:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
    <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

My question is, if same code runs on edge node of the cluster(I create fat jar), then why I get "`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Action`"?? I might get some network error.

If anyone might have face this issue, Please share your experience to solve this issue!!

Comment: Please post your pom.xml. seems you are missing the jar file or else it might have corrupted while gets downloaded in your local repo. That's why you are getting zip exception as well.

Comment: @PraveenKumar: I have updated the question with maven dependency, please refer again my question.